# How do I change the color of the default textfield label in Mui v5?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I have been trying to change the color of the default label for a textfield in mui v5.  I haven't had any luck despite trying many things.

Here is what my textfield looks like:

```
  <TextField
            sx={{
              input: {
                  color: 'blue'
              },
              // fontStyle: 'italic'
              // MuiOutlinedInput-input MuiInputBase-input MuiInputBase-inputSizeSmall css-pfigon-MuiInputBase-input-MuiOutlinedInput-input
// 
            //  "&:hover input": { color: 'red' }, 
              "&:hover .MuiOutlinedInput-root": {
                "& > fieldset": { border: '2px solid #40D61A'},
              },
              "& .MuiOutlinedInput-root": {
                "& > fieldset": { border: "solid 1px green"},
              },
              "& .MuiOutlinedInput-root.Mui-focused": {
                "& > fieldset": {
                  borderColor: "blue",
                },
              },
              "& .MuiInputBase-root": {
                color: 'darkBlue',
              },
              "& .MuiInputBase-root.Mui-focused": {
                color: 'blue',
              },
               "& .MuiOutlinedInput-root.Mui-focused .MuiOutlinedInput-input": {
                color: 'blue"'
              },
              "& .MuiInputLabel-outlined    .MuiInputLabel-sizeSmall": {
                color: 'red'
              },
              "& .MuiInputLabel-animated.Mui-focused": {
                color: 'black'
              },
            }}
```

[image]

I am able to get the borders to change, I am able to get the text to change while focused... but I am unable to get the initial labels to change.  Any help would be greatly appreciated thank you.

Comment: Try to setup [your color palette](https://mui.com/material-ui/customization/palette/#adding-new-colors), then by using [**color** prop](https://mui.com/material-ui/api/text-field/#props) change your background

Answer (score 1):

You can create your own custom `theme` and provide it to your app.

**Your Theme**

```
import { createTheme } from "@mui/material";

const myTheme = createTheme({
    palette:{
       light: "#abffbb",
       main: "#00ffbb",
       dark: "#ffffbb",
    }
});
```

You can also only add `main`. `light` and `dark` will be taken accordingly by MUI itself.

**Providing Theme**

```
<ThemeProvider theme={MyTheme}>
    <TextField variant='outlined' label='Text field' />
    <TextField variant='filled' label='Text field' />
    <TextField variant='standard' label='Text field' />
</ThemeProvider>
```

Now the `borderColor` and the color of label text will be same as `main` color

Here is the <kbd>[codesandbox link](https://codesandbox.io/s/stoic-jones-bje9v8?file=/src/App.js)</kbd> you can play with